# Relative Date filtering Query Editor - Power BI

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, calendar, powerquery

I don't understand the logic of Power Query Editor.
I have a big table with data from 2019 to 2024 (one column contains the monthly information).
I want to filter the data by the date of that column, but it has to be dynamic.

Two options:

- The data I want to consider is "Current month -2". So all historical data minus current month.
- The data I want to consider is a parameter extracted from somewhere (e.g. I set the latest month to consider manually somewhere in an Excel, which usually is "current month -1" but not always (best).

I would be happy with any of the two solutions.

Currently I found somewhere this formula which filters out vs last month:
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",each [Month]< Date.From(Date.StartOfMonth(DateTime.LocalNow())))

But somehow I do not find the way to go 2 months back.

Thanks a lot!
BR

Comment: You would use the [Date.AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-addmonths) function.  Then you can check that the date in your table is between that date and the current date.

Comment: If you require more assistance, please **edit your question** to provide an example of your data **AS TEXT** which can be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Consider using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)